# Detect touch on custom annotionVIew

Tags: ios, annotations, android-mapview, uigesturerecognizer

How to detect touch on custom annotationView in  (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event ?

I use that code, but it not works

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if (touch.view == [CustomAnnotationView class])
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if the touch's view is a CustomAnnotationView class.

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotationView class]])
    {
```

Comment: spasibo 4yvak, viry4il